# Is SOAP Outdated?

Tags: android, ios, web-services, soap, windows-8

I wish to open up my PHP website to Android, iOS and Windows 8/Windows Phone.

I've been looking at the library for PHP SOAP and I've got it working.

Although I've done this, I've seen people posting online that SOAP is "outdated".

Is it, and if so, what are the alternatives?

Comment: What website is that, or what service are you offering?

Comment: Saying it was flat out outdated certainly is incorrect. SOAP has its points and especially for real transactions, SOAP is invaluable. For simple every day data, JSON would be a better choice as it is a lot easier to parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOAP is usually quite "heavy" when designing and consuming and it's based on XML. For a more lightweight approach you might want to look at REST-style APIs that are easier to implement, adopt and can purely be based on JSON which makes it easy to consume those services with Javascript/Client side technology:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST

There may be good use cases for SOAP though - but I figure you'll find those mainly in heavy enterprise applications.

Comment: I really like soap style web services they have a signature file where you can actually give to people and they will understand what it does, someone else can use your soap web service without you having to explain what it does and what it can return accept. So it really depends on the application, but if I'm allowed to choose myself I would always go with SOAP.

Comment: I like your comment @GabrielNetto. SOAP definitely has its great advantages, especially those you mention. However, it does not come easy and takes more brain and code to parse. That is where JSON comes to place. Overall I guess developers saying that SOAP was outdated have never really understood the point of SOAP. Still, in the world of mobile apps, JSON commonly is the weapon of choice.

Comment: @GabrielNetto REST is most commonly used with HTTP and XML/JSON. In SOAP, you're basically performing a remote method invocation. You specify the method and the arguments in a SOAP envelope. In case of ROA (Resource Oriented Architecture, which basically means REST over HTTP), the methods are specified by universal HTTP verbs, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc. The body only contains the data and metadata. As long as the creators of a service follow the conventions defined as REST, they can define a contract using XSD and WADL files.

Comment: @GabrielNetto in other words, you don't call methods, instead, you change the state of resources. It revolves around commonly known principles mapping of CRUD operations to HTTP verbs. Here's a [description of what you can do with HTTP methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). REST is more simple and lightweight as it utilizes and embraces an existing protocol instead of requiring you to specify the very same things in XML, the parsing of which may take a long time.

Comment: As for one replacing the other. I think SOAP will survive, at least for the next couple of years. I suppose the abundance of tools and additional standards (improving security and reliability) will continue to make it preferable for business environments. REST is a winner in case of publicly available APIs and mobile clients, though.